# Need to Duplicate almost same line below xml file using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need to duplicate almost same line below the same existing line using notepad++

File1:

Before:

```
<add key="CustomFolder" value="CustomFolderTest" />
```

After:enter code here

```
 <add key="CustomFolder" value="CustomFolderTest" />
 <add key="CustomFolder1" value="CustomFolder2Test" />
```

File2:

Before:

```
 <add key="CustomFolder" value="CustomFolderabc" />
```

After:

```
 <add key="CustomFolder" value="CustomFolderabc" />
 <add key="CustomFolder1" value="CustomFolder2abc" />
```

up to 75 files Like this multiple files have different value for CustomFolder     key and that should duplicate in second line

is this possbile with regular expression in Notepad++?

Comment: The second line is always the name of the customer folder with a "1" at the end for the key and a "2" at the end for the value? Otherwise, what are the links between the first and second line?

Comment: Yes Second line key value is always "CustomFolder1" and value for second line should contain "CustomFolder2abc" (CustomFolder2+value of CustomFolder value i.e, abc)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `(<add key="CustomFolder" value="CustomFolder(\w+)" />)`
Replace with: `$1\n<add key="CustomFolder1" value="CustomFolder2$2" />`

Comment: Your solution is much simpler ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following replacement (with "Regular Expression" checked):

Find what: `(<add key="CustomFolder)(" value="CustomFolder)(\w+" />)`

Replace with: `\1\2\3\n\11\22\3`

...

If "CustomFolder" is a varying value, you could try:

Find what: `<add key="(\w+)(" value="\1)(\w+" />)`

Replace with: `<add key="\1\2\3\n<add key="\11\22\3`

This pattern replace `key=<key> value=<key><text>` to `key=<key> value=<key><text> \n key=<key>1 value=<key>2<text>`